# How to hide function parameters' types in outline?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already disabled **Outline: Show Variables** in the settings, but they are still there.

For example the function is `void OnDeinit(const int reason)`, and in outline it's like this now: `OnDeinit(const int)`.

[image: outline screenshot]

Can I have it like `OnDeinit()` or even better like `OnDeinit`?

Comment: what programming language? what language support extension? what version of that extension? give version number.

Comment: @starball language is mql5, MQL Tools v2.1.0 is installed, in the status bar in lower right corner C++ is selected as language mode.

Comment: @starball I disabled MQL Tools. made `"outline.showTypeParameters": false`, and Outline still shows `OnDeinit(const int)`.